# Why can't this limit be proved using definition like others?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

$$\lim_{x\to 1} {\frac1x} = 1$$
Can anybody show me a complete proof using the definition. Thanks in advance!

By the definition means proving that: For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exist $\delta > 0$ where $|1/x - 1| < \epsilon$ when $0 < |x - 1| < \delta$.

Comment: What's your definition?

Comment: for every epsilon > 0 there exist delta > 0 where |1/x - 1| < epsilon when 0 < |x - 1| < delta

Comment: yeah i'm talking about that @crash

Comment: It can be proved from the definition, like the others. Hint: In particular, make sure that $\delta\le 1/2$. Then if $0<|x-1|\lt \delta$, then $\left|\frac{1}{x}\right| \lt 2|x-1|$.

Comment: but why take delta <= 1/2 ??

Comment: @AlvarezV.Keo You can pick any suitable $\delta > 0$. Here, you cannot pick $\delta > 1$. If you pick any $\delta>1$ (say, e.g., $\delta=2$), then your neighborhood $(1-\delta,1+\delta)$ would include the vertical asymptote $x=0$, which we do not want.

Comment: For simpler functions, you don't have to include this extra $\delta < 1/2$ restriction.  However, $1/x$ is not linear and the rate at which it approaches $1$ depends on how far away you are from $1$.  Since, by definition, a limit is only concerned with things that are near the limit, we can restrict ourselves to a small region around 1.  You could've picked $\delta < 0.75$ or $\delta < 0.25$, but that will change what you pick for the second restriction on $\delta$.  $\delta < \epsilon/2$ is suitable for $0.5 < x < 1.5$.

Comment: @AlvarezV.Keo:  I updated my answer below with a thorough explanation behind my choice of $\delta$.  I hope this makes more sense, let me know if you're still uncertain about something.

Comment: just to make thing clear: what about the value of delta for f(x) = 1/sqrt(x) ??

Answer (score 6):

If $|x-1| < \min(1/2,\epsilon/2)$, then $|x| > 1/2$ and

$$\left|\frac1{x}-1\right|= \frac{|x-1|}{|x|}< 2|x-1|<\epsilon$$

Comment: how do you know that 1/|x| < 2 ??

Comment: As he said, $|x| \gt 1/2$, so $1/|x| \lt 2$  That was the point of putting $1/2$ in the min.

Comment: Because $|x-1| < 1/2 \implies -1/2 < x-1 < 1/2 \implies x > 1/2 \implies 1/x < 2$

Comment: but what gives you the idea of taking the value of |x-1| < min(1/2, e/2) ??

Comment: To be more explicit, $1-|x|\leq |1-x|=|x-1| < 1/2$ using the reverse triangle inequality, so $|x| >1/2$. Multiple nice techniques in this simple problem: this one, and the $\min(1/2,\epsilon/2)$ idea.

Comment: @AlvarezV.Keo *That idea* you reference is part of the *art* of proving these limits formally. Takes time and practice. You'll get there if you keep plugging away though.

Comment: If $x$ is close enough to $1$ then we have a positive lower bound so we can upper bound $1/|x|$. I just picked $1/2$ somewhat arbitrarily.

Comment: The idea is that you have $|x-1|/|x|$ which you want less than $\epsilon$, so you make some initial restriction on $\delta$, i.e. that $\delta \leq 1/2$, to give $|x|>1/2$ so you can get rid of the $|x|$ part. The intuition is that you can make $x$ as close to $1$ as you want, so bigger than $1/2$ is easy.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Pick $\delta = \min\left\{ 0.5 , \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right\}$.

Then, for any $x$ such that $|x - 1| < \delta$, we have $|x - 1| < 0.5$ and $|x - 1| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

The first inequality tells us that $x = |x| > 0.5$.  Multiplying the second inequality by 2 gives
$$ 2|x-1| < \epsilon $$

Then,

$$ \left| 1 - \frac{1}{x} \right| = \frac{|x-1|}{|x|} < \frac{|x-1|}{0.5} = 2|x-1| < \epsilon $$

This proves that $\frac{1}{x}$ gets arbitrarily close to $1$ when $x \to 1$.  We have shown that, for any given $\epsilon$, there is a choice of $\delta$ such that any $x$ value within $\delta$ of $x = 1$ will give us a value for $1/x$ that is within $\epsilon$ of 1.

EDIT:  Here is my rationale for picking $\delta = \min\left\{ 0.5 , \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right\}$.  I want to pick a $\delta$ such that eventually I get

$$ \left| 1 - \frac{1}{x} \right| < \epsilon$$

Rearranging this gives

$$ |x - 1 | < |x| \epsilon$$

Normally, if the $x$ weren't there, it would be very obvious what to choose for $\delta$ (namely it would just be whatever is on the right hand side of the inequality).  $\delta$ can't depend on $x$ because logically that would not make sense (we have to pick $x$ based on $\delta$ later, so $\delta$ can't depend on $x$).

So, to get around the $x$ on the right hand side, we can simply choose to study a small region around $x = 1$.  When you take limits, you only care about the stuff near the limit anyway, so this makes sense.  Normally, I would choose $\delta < 1$ because 1 is a nice number, but $1/x$ blows up when we get to $x = 0$, so we have to refine a little further.  $0.5$ is a nice number, but you can really just pick anything less than 1. **You can pick just about any restriction for delta here, as long as it doesn't include any weird parts of the function you're taking a limit of.**

In my case, I went with 0.5.  So, by enforcing $\delta < 0.5$, I am guaranteeing that we only look at $x$ values from $0.5 < x < 1.5$.  Generally speaking, the smaller a $\delta$ is, the more likely it is to work.  On the right hand side, if we only consider $0.5 < x < 1.5$, the smallest this expression can be would be at $x = 0.5$.  Thus, if we choose $\delta < 0.5 \epsilon$, we are guaranteed that $ |x - 1 | < |x| \epsilon$ will hold true.

We have placed two restrictions on $\delta$, so in order for both to be satisfied, $\delta$ must be the minimum of both of them.

Comment: thanks I'm getting parts of it but would you mind giving me the value of delta if f(x) = 1/sqrt(x) so that I could see the pattern?

Comment: It depends on the function $f(x)$.  Also, there are always an infinite number of choices of $\delta$ that work.  The fact that it's $1/x$ isn't special.  You'd have to do something similar for most $f(x)$.  For example, let's consider $\lim_{x->2} x^2 = 4$.  We want to find $\delta$ such that $|x^2 - 4| < \epsilon$.  Rearranging gives $|x-2|< \epsilon/|x+2|$.  Again, the critical point is that the right hand side depends on $x$.  Graphically, what's happening is that how fast $f(x) = x^2$ approaches the limit of interest changes depending on what $x$ is, so we can't just blindly pick $\delta$.

Comment: In this situation $f(x) = x^2$ is a nice function that doesn't blow up, so we can restrict $\delta$ almost freely.  I like the number 1.  Perhaps you like the number 2 or 0.5 or $\pi$, but I will choose 1 here.  Any number will pretty much work here.  So, I will restrict $\delta < 1$, which means $1 < x < 3$ since our limit is at 2.  Then, within $1 < x < 3$, the smallest that $\epsilon/|x+2|$ can be is $\epsilon/5$, at $x = 3$.  So, we choose $\delta = \min \left\{ 1 , \epsilon/5 \right\}$.

Comment: Thanks but I need to see the value of f(x) = 1/sqrt(x) for verification purposes. Could you give me that? just the value

Comment: It depends on where your limit is.  For $\lim_{x->1} 1/\sqrt{x} = 1$, one $\delta$ that would work would be $\delta = \min \left\{ \frac{1}{2} ,  \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} \left( \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} + 1 \right) \right\}$.  This one is a bit trickier to come up with.  Let me know if you can't see where that comes from.

Comment: I know where that last part of the delta comes from but why the first part min(1/2 ...) ??

Comment: Like I said, you can usually pick any value for this first part.  I would pick $1$, but then we have the unfortunate problem of including stuff near $x = 0$, which is where $1/\sqrt{x}$ would blow up.  I like the number $1/2$.  Other acceptable choices would be $0.25,0.75,0.234234,0.43534958$, or really just about anything less than 1.  The second part will change if you choose something other than $1/2$.  You should try it with something like 0.25 to see for yourself.

Comment: Ok i see thank you so much for your time and your answer!

Comment: You're welcome!  I like that you have a drive to understand it rather than just accepting it as black magic.  Also, I hope this is obvious, but I accidentally left off the $\epsilon$ above.  It should be $\delta = \min\left\{ \frac{1}{2} , \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} \left( \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} + 1 \right) \epsilon \right\}$

Comment: yeah I now know why it went like that thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

$| \frac{1}{x} - 1 | = \frac{|1-x|}{|x|} = \frac{|x-1|}{|x-1 + 1|} \leq \frac{|x-1|}{|x-1| - 1}$

We need that $ \frac{|x-1|}{|x-1| - 1} < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$, now
$|x-1|^2 < \epsilon |x-1| - \epsilon \Leftrightarrow |x-1|^2 - \epsilon|x-1| +\epsilon < 0$

by this way you find a $\delta(\epsilon)$ , such that $|x-1| < \delta$

Comment: You're saying that $|x-1+1|\ge |x-1|-1$, but $|x-1+1|+1\ge |x-1+1+1|=|x+1|$ and it's not necessary that $|x+1|\ge |x-1|$, unless $x\ge 0$.

Comment: $|a|-|b| \leq |a-b|$, then $|x-1| - |1| \leq |x-1 + 1|$